# How to make those two borders with pseudo-elements

Tags: css, sass, pseudo-element

[image]

Hi guys, i am trying to do those borders for block with :after and :before pseudo-elements, same thing for button, but i stuck on it.I guess it should be done somehow with borders width, could you help me please with it?

Comment: What have you done so far? Show us your code.

Answer (score 3):

I have just created something like your shared image. Hope this will work for u..

```css
.outer-section{
  background:#fdefe0;
  width:200px;
  height:400px;
  border: 1px solid #c7bcaf;
  border-radius:8px;
  position:relative;
  margin:30px;
}

.outer-section:before {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #fdefe0;
    content: "";
    top: -4px;
    z-index: 2;
}
.outer-section:after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #c7bcaf;
    content: "";
    top: -5px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.inner-section {
    background: transparent;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.inner-section:before {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid #fdefe0;
    content: "";
    bottom: 1px;
    z-index: 2;
}
.inner-section:after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid #c7bcaf;
    content: "";
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.white-bg {
    background: #fff;
    height: 350px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.button-section {
    background: #e88d1c;
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.button-section:before {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
    border-right: 86px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid #e88d1c;
    content: "";
    bottom: -5px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.button-innner {
    background: #fff;
    height: 10px;
    width: 40%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-section">
 <div class="inner-section">
  <div class="white-bg">
  
  </div>
  <div class="button-section">
  <div class="button-innner">
  
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for solution.Btw is it possible to make responsive as well?

Comment: here is updated fiddle. I responsive i have given values in percent format https://fiddle.jshell.net/de23bsyy/